# Add slide numbers to Jupyter Notebook Slides

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, slideshow, page-numbering

I would like to add slide numbers to a Jupyter Notebook slideshow. I found an [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/737) about this, but I am not sure how and if it possible to add slide numbers to your slides in Jupyter Notebook slideshow. Here is some reproducible code to make a slide show:

```
# Jupyter Notebook Slides

I would like to add a slide number here?
```

Using the command in the terminal:

```
jupyter nbconvert test_slides.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add a page number to your slides in a Jupyter Notebook Slideshow?

Comment: The 'jupyter convert' command of the syntax is on the page that is linked from where you link [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/pull/1654#issue-1020071008). I don't know if still syntax. While you suggest you provide an example of 'code', you don't say say how you implement that. (Is that markdown in a single `.ipynb' file? Why not actually link to a gist of a notebook that has multiple slides that you'd want numbered?) More importantly, how do you make your slides? Did you try running on the command line `jupyter nbconvert --to=slides --SlidesExporter.reveal_number='c/t'`? ...

Comment: <continued> Plus from the documentation linked at the page above, there is a setting you need to set in the configuration `Reveal.initialize({ slideNumber: true });`. See [here](https://revealjs.com/slide-numbers/).

Comment: Hi @Wayne, Using `jupyter nbconvert test_slides.ipynb --to slides --SlidesExporter.reveal_number='c/t` did the job! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Wayne in the comments, you could use the following command:

```
jupyter nbconvert notebook_slides.ipynb --to slides --SlidesExporter.reveal_number='c/t'
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see it now has slide numbers!